# Can we have 3 flags destruction for some time?

Tags: feature-request

This site has attracted extra spam in the past few months. As the current case is on English Language & Usage and The Workplace, only 3 flags are required before a spam or offensive post is nuked. Can we have the same mechanism here so spams don't last too long before it pollutes more?

Related: [What's with the amount of spam here?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/417/20889)

For a list of recent spams caught by [SmokeDetector](https://charcoal-se.org/#whats-smokey), see [here](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&site=208&commit=Search). Note it's possible that Smokey missed some of them.

---

**Note:** If this is getting implemented, please inform us ([the Charcoal team](https://charcoal-se.org/pings/#smokey-maintainers)) before actually carrying it out so that we can reduce our autoflagging number to 1, so as not to unilaterally nuke any post.

Comment: Changed tag to feature-request to get attention of admins

Comment: 99.59% TP rate on Astronomy (981tp 4fp)